# How to store data into SQLite database from existing JSON file in Django?

Tags: json, django, sqlite

Suppose I have JSON file

```
{Key1:value,
key2:value,
key3:value}

{Key1:value,
key2:value,
key3:value}
```

Now I want to store this data into SQLite database which should have one table having fields: Key 1, Key 2, Key 3.

How can I save this data into database using script?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/).

First, make a django model that represents the table that you want to create. Key1, Key2, etc. are the fields in your model.

Then, all you need to do is get your data into the correct json format like the one below.

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

Finally, run `python manage.py loaddata <json filepath>`. And you're done!